# ng2-smart-table disabling action button seperately

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

This is my first time working with `ng2-smart-table` and I am finding a way how to disable the action buttons one by one. I can only see a way to disable the whole action button since it is on one `html` tag only.

This is my code

```
<div class="table-lookup-details">
    <ng2-smart-table [settings]="lookupDetailsSettings" [source]="dataSource"
        (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event, itemCategoryCode, itemDDCode)"
        (editConfirm)="onSaveConfirm($event, itemCategoryCode, itemDDCode)"
        (createConfirm)="onCreateConfirm($event, itemCategoryCode, itemDDCode)">
    </ng2-smart-table>
</div>
```

And I cannot find a `disabled` property on its documentation [here](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation)

I know I can do this thing manually using `jQuery` but I am thinking maybe there's a good way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `actions = false` in the setting section like as below :

```
settings = {
    actions: false,
    columns: {
      srno:
      {
        title: 'Serial #'
      },
    }
}
```